# /proc/<pid>/stat children CPU time

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I've been running the following command on my linux box:

```
watch -d -n 1 "cat /proc/19866/stat"
```

The pid above is a pid of Nginx's master process - I would expect the following fields to be changing: 14, 15, 16 and 17 as according to [kernel docs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) those should contain amount of time the process has been scheduled in user/kernel mode (14,15) and its children too (16,17), however running this command in watch I noticed that none of those numbers ever change. Can someone shed a bit more light on this ? I'd like to count some CPU usage stats per process and I thought /proc.. was the place to look.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing a simple shell script using the `ps` command.  Based on the implementation, you can get the command to output only those fields that are interesting to you.

Comment: but isn't ps reading from /proc too ? At least that's what I thought it was doing...